# edit a video in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg-python

I'm trying edit a MP4 video using ffmpeg-python library but I get

> TypeError: 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'input'

Here is my code, directly copied from the [official repository](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python?tab=readme-ov-file#quickstart)):

```
import ffmpeg
x=ffmpeg.input('xx.mp4')
x=ffmpeg.hflip(x)
x=ffmpeg.output(x,'yy.mp4')
ffmpeg.run(x)
```

I'm very confused about this error.
Can anyone help me to figure out??

[error using ffmpeg-library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNxzD.png)

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think `ffmpeg-python` can play sound. It's largely used for converting videos from one format to another.

Comment: FLAC and MP3 are different file formats, there is no "MP3 / FLAC" format, MP3 is lossy while FLAC is lossless.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Nick ODell. I suppose you are right about ffmpeg-pythjon (it's for manipulating videos). I've edited my question

Comment: Is your file called `ffmpeg.py`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Chris, of couse my filename **is different from ffmeg.py**

Comment: You say "of course", but it's a common mistake and your question doesn't tell us...

Comment: I know it can be a common mistake (sometimes I forgot it), thanks for your advice @Chris :)

Answer (score 1):

From [a tiny bit of googling](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/issues/174) : you probably installed the wrong ffmeg python library.
You can use `pip install ffmpeg-python` to be sure to install the correct one.
you can also list the installed modules with `pip list` and manually inspect if there is indeed another module sharing the name ffmpeg.

You can also manually inspect the ffmpeg file to ensure it is the right one :

```py
import ffmpeg
print(ffmpeg)
```

This output something like

```
<module 'ffmpeg' from 'some_path/__init__.py'>
```

You can then open the file `some_path/_ffmpeg.py` and check that it has the desired `input` attribute.
As of `ffmpeg-python` version `0.2.0`, the file begins like this :

```py
from ._utils import basestring

from .nodes import (
    filter_operator,
    GlobalNode,
    InputNode,
    MergeOutputsNode,
    OutputNode,
    output_operator,
)


def input(filename, **kwargs):
    """Input file URL (ffmpeg ``-i`` option)

    Any supplied kwargs are passed to ffmpeg verbatim (e.g. ``t=20``,
    ``f='mp4'``, ``acodec='pcm'``, etc.).

    To tell ffmpeg to read from stdin, use ``pipe:`` as the filename.

    Official documentation: `Main options <https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options>`__
    """
    kwargs['filename'] = filename
    fmt = kwargs.pop('f', None)
    if fmt:
        if 'format' in kwargs:
            raise ValueError("Can't specify both `format` and `f` kwargs")
        kwargs['format'] = fmt
    return InputNode(input.__name__, kwargs=kwargs).stream()

   .......
```

Comment: Thanks @seb, **I only use ffmpeg-python** library (checked with pip list)

Comment: @fede maybe this is a bit overkill but you can try printing the module, and inspect the ```.py``` files at its path to check it has an input attribute ?

Comment: ffmpeg file is OK, I try you code (print(mpeg) and the result is th same as yours))

Comment: Well this is very weird because then ffmpeg **has** an attribute ```input```, which contradicts the error message. I guess this is beyond my limited knowledge, sorry.

Comment: I know @seb, i don'understan this error message, it ha no sense¡¡¡
_ffmpeg.py is the same as yours (0.2.0)
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @fede What happens if you run your file directly from the terminal ?

Comment: I'm on Windows, if I run my code **from python's shell I get the same error**: ffmpeg has no attribute input, it has no sense for me :(

Comment: @fede I am really curious to know the error if you ever find it